# if else on dataframe header giving KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, logic

I have some datafiles from which a user selects via a gui, to determine which pre-processing they need I have an if-else (following example is simplified but produces the traceback) to test which kind of data file it is by the column headers or what is in the comments field.

***Data for file which contains a "Comments" header***

The following works for a file which ***has*** a comments field. When I use it to test a texfile that has no comments field I get an exception - to my way of thinking it should just run the 'else' body when that happens.

**Code**

```
if df["Comments"].str.contains("Sclk" or "segs").any():
    print("this might be OPW data")
else:
    print('NOT opw data')
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../Desktop/tk_gui_grid/get_data_01.py", line 47, in <module>
    if df["Comments"].str.contains("Sclk" or "segs").any():
  File "/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Comments'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if 'Comments' in df.columns and df[df["Comments"].isin(['Sclk', 'segs'])].shape[0] != 0:
    print("this might be OPW data")
else:
    print('NOT opw data')
```